# combining filter with multiple lambda arguments

Tags: python

If I have something like:

`filter(lambda x,y: x + y > 5, [3,6])`
I'm trying to get all pairs of elements whose sum is greater than 5.
I get an error saying lambda expects 2 inputs but only one is given. if I then do `filter((lambda x,y: x + y > 5, [3,6],[6,4]))` then I get an error saying filter has been given too many arguments. Is it possible to accomplish this?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? It is not clear from this context. Are you trying to get all pairs of elements whose sum is greater than 5?

Comment: yes, get all pairs of elements whose sum is greater than 5

Comment: Do you have a list of lists?

Comment: All pairs? What pairs? From where, corresponding how, which direction?

Comment: It might be easier for us to tell what you want to do if you could show us a working version using `for` loops.

Comment: Note you can also use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to first generate all pairs of elements from a single list and _then_ filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets assume you have list of pairs:

```
pairs = [[3,6],[0,4]]
```

Then you can write something like:

```
filter(lambda pair: sum(pair) > 5, pairs)
```

And it should work out OK.  You could also write it like this:

```
filter(lambda pair: pair[0] + pair[1] > 5, pairs)
```

Or (on python2.x ONLY -- This use is definitely not encouraged, I add it here only in case you run into it in some code elsewhere):

```
filter(lambda (x, y): x + y > 5, pairs)
```

---

Note, all of these options are limiting ourselves the the `filter` builtin function.  If we relax that limitation, many (most?) pythonistas will advocate filtering using a list-comprehension instead.  It could look like:

```
[[x, y] for x, y in pairs if x + y > 5]
```

Or:

```
[pair for pair in pairs if sum(pair) > 5]  # look familiar  :-)?
```

Answer (score -2):

Python filter function expects a function with one input and boolean output. Your function arity (Signature) is not so. Each of iterator items is given into the function and if the return value is true, the item would be added to the output.